# ExtJs 6 toolpip for combobox selected item

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

i have done toolpip for  compobox list items

```
 listConfig: {
            itemTpl: [
                '<div data-qtip="{description}">{mydisplayField}</div>'
            ]
```

now I'm trying to show tooltip for selected item,current value
i have search many times but I cant can't do to this .
If you have done task like this pleas tell me.

Answer (score 0):

it was so easy

on afterrender

```
var fieldStore = field.getStore();
Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: field,
    listeners: {
        beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
            var value = field.getValue();
            if (!value && value !== 0) {
                return false; //not show
            }
            var record  = fieldStore.getById(value);
            tip.update(record.get('description'));
        }
    }
});
```